# Why are two lm log models with different bases produce the same predictions?

Tags: r, lm

I am trying to predict values using lm() and predict() functions, and two functions, which are different produce the same values

consider the data.frame

```
d <- structure(list(sample_number = 1:9, 
                    cumSum = c(200.903, 296.329, 370.018, 431.59, 485.14, 533.233, 576.595, 616.536, 654)), 
                    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 9L))
```

I am producing two separate models with different bases. The models are in fact different

```
lmEBase2 <- lm(cumSum~log(sample_number, base = 2),data=d)
lmEBase3 <- lm(cumSum~log(sample_number, base = 3),data=d)
```

however, the predictions are the same

```
logPredBase2 <- predict(lmEBase2, newdata=data.frame(sample_number=1:20))
logPredBase3 <- predict(lmEBase3, newdata=data.frame(sample_number=1:20))
```

```
plot  (d$sample_number, d$cumSum, xlim = c(0, 20), ylim = c(0, 1000), type = "b")
lines (1:20, logPredBase2)
lines (1:20, logPredBase3, col = "red")
```

why?

I expect different shapes of the log curve for different log bases, like shown in wikipedia

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm

Comment: You created a log of the predictor variables. In theory this should not affect the shape of the outcome in a logarithmic manner..it may change the predictions because the predictors are more or less appropriate to the linear outcomes, but log converting a predator does not convert your outcome to a log base

Comment: any suggestions on a better way to do this? My expectation is that my model should behave in a "log-like" manner, i.e. there should be diminished returns of unique observation on adding more samples.

Comment: a linear model always draws a straight line as its prediction. So, there is not path to diminishing returns that is not directly linear, no matter how many observations or the log transformation. If in fact there is a logarithmic relationship between X and y, then you will see this in a scatter plot of X vs y the log transform of one variable (usually X) can make them linearly comparable...but it will not make the outcome non-linear.

Comment: if you are hoping for a polynomial relationship, you need to choose a more appropriate model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we do a linear regression we are fitting a line with the following formula

[image]

where

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Which proves why the intercepts are equal.

Similarly,

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Which is why `229.4*log(2,base = 3) = 144.7` where `229.4` is the coefficient of the second fit and `144.7` is the coefficient of the first fit. And the intercepts are equal.

This explains how the two regressions performed are related.

Now if Fit1 is,

[image]

and  Fit 2 is,

[image]

We can see that Fit2 is equal to Fit1 by again using the change of base.

Since all we used is the change of base, it doesn't matter what base we use, all the fits would be the same.